# Variance of Wilcoxon Rank-Sum Test (no ties)

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

$\newcommand{\E}[1]{\mathbb{E}\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\r}[1]{r\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\P}[1]{\mathbb{P}\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\Var}[1]{\text{Var}\left[#1\right]}$

Given two sets of data $X$ with $m$ points and $Y$ with $n$ points, unioned (keeping duplicates) to create a data set $Z = \{Z_i\}$ with $m + n = N$ data points, the Wilcoxon Rank-Sum Test Statistic is given by
\begin{equation*}
T = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}r(Z_i)\cdot \mathbb{I}(Z_i \in X)\text{,}
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbb{I}(Z_i \in X)$ is $1$ if $Z_i \in X$, $0$ otherwise. ($r(\cdot)$ denotes the rank of the data point.)

Suppose there are no ties. Then 
\begin{align*}
\E{T} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\r{Z_i}\cdot \E{\mathbb{I}(Z_i \in X)} &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\r{Z_i}\cdot\P{Z_i \in X} \\
&= \dfrac{m}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\r{Z_i} \\
&= \dfrac{mN(N+1)}{2N} \\
&= \dfrac{m(N+1)}{2}\text{.}
\end{align*}
This comes out to what it says in the book *Nonparametric Statistical Inference*, 5th ed., by Gibbons and Chakraborti.

Now for $\Var{T}$:
\begin{align*}
\Var{T} &= \Var{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\r{Z_i}\mathbb{I}(Z_i \in X)}\\
&= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\left[\r{Z_i}\right]^2\Var{\mathbb{I}(Z_i \in X)} \\
&= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\left[\r{Z_i}\right]^2\P{Z_i \in X}\left[1-\P{Z_i \in X}\right]\\
&= \left(\dfrac{m}{N}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{m}{N}\right)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\left[\r{Z_i}\right]^2 \\
&= \left(\dfrac{m}{N}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{m}{N}\right)\left[\dfrac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}\right] \\
&= \left(\dfrac{m}{N}\right)\left(\dfrac{N-m}{N}\right)\left[\dfrac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}\right] \\
&= \left(\dfrac{m}{N}\right)\left(\dfrac{n}{N}\right)\left[\dfrac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}\right] \\
&= \dfrac{2N+1}{N}\left[\dfrac{mn(N+1)}{6}\right]
\end{align*}
The answer should be $\dfrac{mn(N+1)}{12}$. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that each $r(Z_i)$ depends implicitly on all of $Z$. Hence you are taking the variance of a sum whose terms are not independent; therefore you are not justified in rewriting this as the sum of the variance of each term -- instead you must also consider the covariances of the cross-terms.